# How to identify the source of low frequency noise from the street?

Tags: sound

Is there a way to identify the source of low frequency (166Hz) noise coming from the street (I suspect from the opposite building in the closed yard in the city)?

The noise comes hearable in the yard as well and comes, maybe from the root or vent system, I can’t be quite sure since I don’t have access there and housekeepers say that nothing there could produce this noise.

Can I without a special expensive equipment somehow localize the direction to the source?

I have good microphone, PC and some other household appliances.

Without getting straight to the roof, just from my window, can I somehow get the exact direction to the source?

I am thinking about:

1. Two moving microphones, parallax, interference and computing direction (and even, possibly the distance) to the source.
2. Cone tube with microphone to make in somewhat “directional microphone”.

Are there any better ways to do so?

I live in the city, so the environment is noisy, but in the night, I can choose some quiet time for measurement.

The problem I am trying to solve is the 166Hz noise that about 25 Db louder than other sounds which passes through the windows (3 glasses of 4 mm) like through a filter that leaves only this noise while cancelling other sounds and working around the clock this drives me crazy.

**Update**

Based on comment below here is the spectrogram of the range 0-200Hz:

[image: Spectrum with closed window 0-200Hz]

(Made by Android [Spectroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.intoorbit.spectrum&hl=en_US&gl=US) application).

*(It shows 165Hz, but usually it is 166Hz, I don't think this difference is important).*

On the 50Hz peak, its loudness varies up to 30Db (can be less or more than on the picture) while loudness on 166Hz usually vary not more than 5Db until there is a strong wind or loud noise (cars, planes, street cleaning, etc.) and I created both frequencies on my PC and I don't bother with 50Hz sound (not so pressing) while I immediately recognized the 166Hz as "the same one annoying sound".

Here is the range 0-1000Hz based on the questions in comments.

With open window:

[image: With open window]

and with closed window:

[image: With closed window]

In dynamics all the "possible spikes" after 200Hz are moving up and down and actually there is no stable spike like this at 166Hz. This could be seen from the bottom part of each chart, not sure what to call it, let me name it a "legend".

I have recording for the sounds, I will share if it would help.

Comment: Option **1** would only work if the two microphones and their circuits are *well matched*. Otherwise you might have to calibrate them before use. There is also an option **3** where you can simply move in the direction you think the sound is coming from and check if it gets louder. "... *25 Db louder than other sounds* ..." How did you conclude this? Have you already made measurements?

Comment: @AJN, I thought about syncing on PC. For example, I could make sync sounds between two microphones (watches?) and then sync up based on this sound. As I stated I can't move in the direction to the source, since it is on (suspiciously) on the root of the opposite house and I am not a Carlson; even if I could to move slightly, with sound this would give very approximate direction. On 25Db, of course, I measured, updated the question with the sound spectrum.

Comment: have you measured in the house with windows closed or at night, outside? certainly, there is a frequency around 166 Hz.  I'd first check the windows open/closed situation to see if the filtering is a matter of your own house.

Comment: The 50Hz power frequency is visible, but your 166 doesn't look like a power line harmonic. Are there any utilities nearby which would use large pumps or generators that run constantly with your sound? Is it there in all seasons?

Comment: @GürkanÇetin, this is the chart with the closed windows. I measured both with open and closed windows and as I mentioned in the question, I measured even in the yard, so I am sure in two things: (1) the sound is not related to my flat since the same 166Hz is in the yard from the direction of that roof. (2) windows don't help, since if I open them other frequencies become much louder, but this one changes not so dramatically. If this would help, I can post chart with the open window.

Comment: @PeteW, yes there is a restaurant at that house and they use vent systems one of which goes with tube to the roof (7th floor building, as well as mine floor is seventh opposite to this building). This is the suspect number one. All seasons, all hours in a day, becomes slightly less noticeable when there is snow, rain or strong wind. Sound never stops, don't vary the frequency. We have a street behind this house, but I measured even when no cars were passing by at all, the same sound while all other frequencies quiet.

Comment: @PeteW, on the 50Hz and 166Hz. The 50Hz varies during the day up to 30Db in a range and I created both frequencies on my PC and I don't bother with 50Hz sound while I immediately recognized the 166Hz as "the same one annoying sound".

Comment: Does the spectrum contain noticeable harmonics of 166? especially odd multiples, 500 and 833? Collecting a longer audio sample may help improve the spectrum

Comment: @PeteW, no more stable peaks of such loudness after 166 Hz. With open window all on the higher frequencies (up to 1000Hz) the loudness is almost the same as around 200 Hz. With closed window the spectrum line goes down on higher frequencies. If it would help, I can post both charts.

Comment: Sure why not... The harmonics would be expected to be quieter (like -10dB or -20dB for the 3x)

Comment: @PeteW, the question has been updated with the charts. I can share the recorded sounds in mp3 if it would help.

Comment: Is it possible that it's a standing wave in the extract flue? 343 m/s / 166 = 2.066 m.

Comment: @Transistor, the only thing I could say that they have a tube which goes from the restaurant on the first floor to the roof above the 7th floor with the diameter about 70 cm. What is 2.066 m in your calculation? The length of the standing wave? If so, how it could be interconnected with this equipment?

Comment: OK, that's a long tube. 2 m is the wavelength for 166 Hz. I was wondering if you were getting a harmonic but maybe not - unless the long tube is giving some ultra-low frequencies and the 166 Hz is a harmonic of that? It's an interesting problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several important clues here, as follows.

First we note the very strong 50Hz spike. I will assume from the spelling of your name that you live in a place with 50Hz AC mains. Many different types of electrical machinery running on 50Hz will produce 50HZ noise- in particular, power transformers in which the core laminations are loose will "hum" audibly at the line frequency, and synchronous AC motors will hum at line frequency too as well as at their rotating speed.

Next we note that the amplitude of the 166Hz signal is almost the same as that of the 50Hz spike, and just as sharp. I don't think this is a coincidence, which means the source of the 166Hz signal is coincident with the source of the 50Hz noise. This implies a large electric motor (perhaps ~several kilowatts).

To radiate that noise across a street and into your yard means the source is most likely an air-circulating fan of some sort which is using its intake or discharge duct as a *loudspeaker*, since for example a water pump in a building would be much harder to hear since it isn't well-coupled to the air outside of the building.

166Hz translates into a spin speed of 8300RPM for the fan- if it had only one blade, which fans never do. So if we postulate that the fan has six blades, for example, we get a fan speed of 1400RPM which would be in the typical range for a single-phase, one horsepower electric motor driving an HVAC fan. Note also that it is common to drive a big fan with a V-belt and pulleys; the fan turns more slowly than the motor shaft in this case which alters the relationship between motor speed, fan speed, and blade number.

Now, how to trace the sound back to its source? This is hard for low-frequency sounds because they radiate in all directions and bounce off of large objects like apartment walls. This creates something called *multipath* in which a reflection can be mistaken for the source, and *phase cancellation* in which a reflection will destructively interfere with another reflection reaching your microphone from a slightly different direction.

You can improve your chances of getting useful information from a microphone analysis by using a very long, skinny *shotgun microphone* which is highly directional, but the problem with a shotgun mic is that they are most effective at higher frequencies and less so at lower frequencies. To make a shotgun mic work well at low frequencies requires a mic extension assembly that is several meters long.

Comment: @Damir Tenishev, I will edit my answer with more info. -NN

Comment: Thank you for the update in the question (1). Do you know any analyzing software mentioned in the question (2) in my comment above? And getting back on the first question, am I correct that for sound (especially low frequency) it is next to impossible with household equipment like microphones, PC, etc. to build loudness map like people do for radiowaves  making maps of sky or WiFi networks?

Comment: There are a whole bunch of sound analysis programs that run on PC's; these are used by professional musicians to manipulate and analyze their home studio recordings. the ones designed for apple products are the easiest to use. Their quality is only limited by the quality of the microphones that are used with them. Sorry I cannot recommend any specific maker of the software!

Comment: I mostly meant a kind of CAD/CAM system software which could recognize the type of device producing sound or give analysis on the type of sound and its nature. Anyway, I got the idea, I will look for one. So far I had experience with Sound Forge Pro, but it is a general-purpose sound editor, although with many problem-oriented plugins. Anyway, I have to access to it at the moment. I got your answer, thank you. I will remove my comments below since they are covered by your updated answer. Fill free to adjust your comments below, then.

Comment: Any clues on my second question in the comment about creating a sound-source-map?